# Make "cmd /c" command in foreach UNIQUE

Tags: powershell

I have a script that runs a command to launch a PowerShell script called Process.ps1 to process some cubes in a table.

```
$Table = Query "SELECT * from [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input' ORDER BY [sequence]"

$i=0
$CUBE = @()

foreach($row in $Table)
{   
    Write-Host "`r`n---------------------------START of Script-----------------------------"
    Write-Host "`r`n [Application] :  $App_input"
    Write-Host " [Script]      :  $Script"
    $i++
    $CUBE = $row.Item("cube_name")
    $CUBE = $CUBE | Select-Object -Unique
    #Write-Host " > CUBE $($i): $($CUBE[-1])`n"
    cmd /c "runPowerShell.bat $Script $($CUBE)"    #where $Script is Process.ps1 script that processes on each CUBE selected from table in order
}
```

For some reason, it's running the processing on the same cube TWICE.

How can I add a "UNIQUE" aspect to the `cmd /c "runPowerShell.bat $Script $($CUBE)"` command so that if the same `$CUBE` is passed back again it ignores it and loops for next different cube to process?

There is a `Select-Object -Unique` but thats for objects, not commands...

Comment: I'd guess that your database query returns multiple rows with the same cube name. Piping each row through `Select-Object -Unique` doesn't help there, since each row contains only one name. Can you change the SQL query to `SELECT DISTINCT cube_name FROM ... `?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers isnt that the same as $CUBE += $row.Item("cube_name") | Select-Object -Unique ? because i tried that and it didnt suffice

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers going by your suggestion, if i do use $CUBE = SELECT DISTINCT cube_name FROM ...., how can i change my for loop to loop through that then? cause foreach would be missing something, like it would be foreach($CUBE in...???) {cmd /c "runPowerShell.bat $Script $($CUBE)"}

Comment: I meant `$Table = Query "SELECT DISTINCT cube_name FROM ..."`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers error: "Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
specified.""

Comment: So, change the `ORDER BY` clause to `ORDER BY cube_name`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers No it has to be by sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I modified my query statement as such:

```
$Table = Query "SELECT DISTINCT[cube_name], [sequence] from [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input' ORDER BY [sequence]"
```

It now just stores one distinct cube and so the `cmd /c "runPowerShell.bat $Script $($CUBE)"` runs just that cube once